# How do I prove that $\frac{x\ln(x)+1}{x}$ tends to $\infty$ as $x$ tends to $0^+$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I prove that $$\frac{x\ln(x)+1}{x}$$ tends to $\infty$ as $x$ tends to $0^+$ ?

I am not able to able to apply L'Hospital's Rule because the numerator itself is in Indeterminate form.

Comment: Hint: it suffices to show $x \ln x \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$.

Comment: Apply $\textit{L'Hopital}$ to the function $\ln(x)/(1/x)$ and its limit will be $0$, resting the final one $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}1/x=+\infty$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Thank you ! I understood it now :).

Comment: Change to $t=\frac{1}{x}\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=2\ln(x)-x$ for $x>2$.

$f'(x)=\frac{2-x}{x}<0$

$\implies f$ decreasing at $[2,+\infty)$.

$\implies \forall x>2\;f(x)<2(\ln(2)-1)<0$

$\implies \forall x>4\;\; \ln(x)-\sqrt{x}<0$

$\implies \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=0$

$\implies \lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln(x)=0$

$\implies \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x\ln(x)+1}{x}=+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

With the change of variable $x=e^{-t}$ it is enough to show that
$$ \lim_{t \to +\infty}\left(-t+e^t\right) = +\infty $$
but that is quite trivial. If you like, by convexity, $e^t\geq et$ for any $t\geq 1$.